# Split top navigation into multiple columns sorted vertically

Tags: navigation

I have my top navigation spread across 4 columns.

Currently, it looks like:

> Alink | Alink | Blink | Blink
>
> Clink | Clink | Dlink | Dlink
>
> Elink | Elink | Flink | Flink

I need it to be:

> Alink | Blink | Dlink | Elink
>
> Alink | Clink | Dlink | Flink
>
> Blink | Clink | Elink | Flink

How can this be achieved in Magento?

Comment: Doesn't make much sense. Are those all top level categories?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said that these are child categories displayed in a drop down box when hovering over their parent category.

Comment: Could you provide a link or screenshot. Your question makes no sense.

Comment: http://www.asos.com - hover over "men" and you'll see the category list under the heading "Shop by product" is split into 2 columns, the list is sorted vertically.

Comment: You're aware that is not a Magento site, right?

Comment: Yes. It's an example of what I'm trying to achieve. The platform is irrelevant.

Comment: You do not provide enough information. You should at least post the code which you tried so far. It seems that this is a CSS / frontend styling question, so the code parts especially in that area are relevant.

Comment: Was your question answered? Then please mark a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be just re-sort categories in admin in a desired order.

If it not acceptable the only solution I see is to create an extension overriding `Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation` and customize `_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml()` method. However overriding Magento classes is not encouraged.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a Magento question particularly unless you want to re-order the list items with PHP otherwise you just need to do it in the admin as Tim said.

It's not possible to have your source order of list items not change and achieve what you want purely with CSS and be solid cross-browser.

This article is describing what you want I think and has some solutions (all with modifying mark-up or source order): http://alistapart.com/article/multicolumnlists

There's plenty of JS solutions to help you acheive this, eg: http://codeasily.com/jquery/multi-column-list-with-jquery

Comment: I was hoping to achieve this with PHP as any jQuery solution I've found (and thank you for the link to that plugin) is too slow. I was hoping somebody could help me to do what that jQuery plugin does but with PHP - presumably in Topmenu.php